# Is there a maximally consistent set of propositions containing this two particular sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I was given the following problem.

> **Problem.** Let $\Gamma$ a consistent set with propositions using only $\{p_{2i}\}$ and $\{\bot, \neg, \lor, \land, \to\}$. Is there a maximally consistent set that contains $\Gamma$ and that also contains $\{p_{1} \land \neg p_{3}\}$

My first intuition is that whichever maximally consistent set contains both sets must be made of all atoms $p_{i}$. Otherwise adding to the set an atom not already in it preserves its consistency.

I hence considered a consistent set $\Theta$ that includes $\Gamma$ and $\{p_{1} \land \neg p_{3}\}$ and in whose formulas all possible atoms $p_{i}$ are contained. I believe then the set

$$
\Lambda = \{\varphi \in PROP : \Theta \vdash \varphi\}
$$

(this is, the set of all possible derivations from $\Theta$) is maximally consistent. However, I have not  been able to prove this.

The set is consistent because $\Theta$ is consistent and hence any valuation $f$ under which $\Theta$ is true makes its derivations true. But how can I prove it is maximally consistent?

If it isn't, what is the correct approach to the problem?

Comment: Absent a definition of $i\equiv 0\pmod 2$ you might as well just name them $p_i.$ Is this inside some axiom system? Do we know somehow the $p_1$ should be false?

Comment: $i \equiv 0 \mod 2$ means $i$ is even. I changed it to make it clearer.

Comment: But "is even" is also undefined without an axiom system. Or do you mean there is only $p_0,p_2,\dots?$ If that is the meaning, then use $p_{2i}.$

Comment: No, the set $\Gamma$ consists only of atoms with an even index. For example, $\Gamma$ could be $\{p_0, p_4\}$ or $\{p_2 \to p_4, p_4, p_6 \land p_8\}$, but it could never include $\neg p_{1} \land \neg p_{3}$

Comment: Okay, write it as $p_{2i}.$ It was unclear that you didn't mean that $p_i$ is the statement "$i$ is even."

Comment: Oh! I see how I was confusing. I'll change it.

Comment: Even better, you can write $p_1,p_2,\dots$ for your starting statements  and then add $q_1,q_2$ to the mix.

Comment: I have come to think that if $\Theta$ contains *all* atoms then $\Lambda$ must be maximally consistent. To see why, consider a $\phi \not\in \Lambda$. Such $\phi$ is not an atom because all atoms are in $\Theta$ and hence in $\Lambda$ as well. If $\phi$ were true under whichever valuations make $\Theta$ true, then it would be derivable from $\Theta$ because all atoms are in $\Theta$. Then $[\phi]_{f} = 0$  for any valuation $f$ that bestows $\Theta$ with consistency. Then $\Lambda \cup \{\phi\}$ is not consistent.

Comment: It's certainly true that any maximally consistent set of propositions is equivalent to a map: $P\to\{\top,\bot\},$ where $P$ is your set of atomic propositions. And any consistent set of propositions is included in a maximal consistent set of propositions.